# Replacing/substituting text with a forward slash in VIM

Tags: vim, replace, textedit

I'm trying to replace the first part of a pathing in a long file I have.

Currently, the part I want to replace reads

```
CurrentDir
```

And I want to replace it with

```
NewPath/ToDirectory
```

The problem is I cannot find how to format the replace to incorperate the additional /ToDirectory part of it. I would greatly appreciate any help on this matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is escaping the forward slash, then simply use a different separator character:

```
:%s,CurrentDir,NewPath/ToDirectory,g
```

This even works in any version of sed(1).

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the `/` in your substitution:

```
:%s/CurrentDir/NewPath\/ToDirectory/g
```

Or forgo the escaping and use a different delimiter:

```
:%s#CurrentDir#NewPath/ToDirectory#g
```